# Display a factorial sequence as a string

Tags: c++, string, integer, factorial, function-definition

// here is my code to find a factorial of a number:

```
int get_factorial(int num)
{
   auto sum = 1;
   while(num > 0)
   {
       sum = sum * num;
       num--;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

// this works to give me the factorial but my assignment wants me to return a string. so if my parameter is 5, instead of returning 120 like my code does currently I need it to return a string that says "1x2x3x4x5 = 120". "5x4x3x2x1 = 120" should also work.

I'm unsure where to start. I thought maybe creating a string and appending each sum as it goes through the loop but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Right now you're building a factorial in a loop. In the same loop you can build a string of appending/prepending `num` and an `x` with each iteration.

Comment: There is a `0!` that your function did not consider.  As a matter of fact, what string would you return for `0!`?

Comment: @WhozCraig this is what I imagined but I don't quite know what that looks like. Im assuming I need to initialize a string before the loop. I get stuck because "num" is an int, so how do you append an int?

Comment: @LauraCandelaria `std::to_string` was mentioned in the first comment.  Have you investigated using it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Im in a freshman level class and because it's not something I've learned in class I can't use it.

Comment: @LauraCandelaria -- The `std::to_string` is how to convert an integer to a string: `std::string s; x = 10; s = std::to_string(x);`.  There is no easier way to do this.  So either use the easier way (`std::to_string`), or use semi-advanced techniques, which you say you cannot use.

Comment: I used std::to_string and it works! I doubt I will lose more than 2 or 3 points if any. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @LauraCandelaria You really shouldn't be losing any points.  The way you convert an integer to a string is `std::to_string`, `sprintf`, `std::ostringstream`, and `std::format` (and I may have missed a few other functions).  You do not want to attempt to write your own code to do this, unless again, you are well beyond the beginner stage.  If you were to hand in code that took an integer and converted it to a string without using those functions I mentioned, the teacher would suspect you cheated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my teacher encourages using stackoverflow when we get stuck on assignments. we have learned about the string class so std::to_string is actually probably fair game, it just hasn't been explicitly brought up in class. He will assume I looked online but I don't think he would consider it cheating unless I literally copied and pasted someone else's code. In this case I used my existing code and added a string initializer(result), appended each "num" and '*' inside the loop, and the returned result + std::to_string(num) + "=" + std::to_string(sum);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment is not easy for beginners like you and me.:)

I can suggest the following solution shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_factorial( unsigned int n )
{
    std::string result;
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    while (n > 1)
    {
        result += std::to_string( n ) + 'x';
        factorial *= n--;
    }

    return result + std::to_string( n ) + " = " + std::to_string( factorial );
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << get_factorial( i ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 = 1
1 = 1
2x1 = 2
3x2x1 = 6
4x3x2x1 = 24
5x4x3x2x1 = 120
6x5x4x3x2x1 = 720
7x6x5x4x3x2x1 = 5040
8x7x6x5x4x3x2x1 = 40320
9x8x7x6x5x4x3x2x1 = 362880
```

Alternatively the function can look also the following way as in that demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_factorial( unsigned int n )
{
    std::string result = std::to_string( n == 0 ? 0 : 1 );
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i++ < n; )
    {
        result += 'x' + std::to_string(i);
        factorial *= i;
    }

    return result  + " = " + std::to_string( factorial );
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << get_factorial( i ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 = 1
1 = 1
1x2 = 2
1x2x3 = 6
1x2x3x4 = 24
1x2x3x4x5 = 120
1x2x3x4x5x6 = 720
1x2x3x4x5x6x7 = 5040
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8 = 40320
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9 = 362880
```

Pay attention to that the type `unsigned long long int` can store the maximum value of factorial for `n` equal to `20`.

Comment: sorry to burst your bubble vlad, but at 290k rep I dont think you are a beginner anymore

Comment: @dwcanillas Till now I have no job because I can not pass an interview. The response is that I know too little in programming.

Comment: @OP , make sure you give vlad credit when you hand your assignment in

Comment: Sounds about right for the times, Vlad. You can add an order of magnitude to the frustration level if you're at/above the age of 45. Unless you share a drug habit, diarrhetic social media circle, common dystopian social hierarchy opinion, or combinations of all the above, your talent needs to be off the chart to make an impact in post-2020 interviews. Feel for ya man.

Comment: @WhozCraig Everyone needs super duper programmers who know everything there is to know about programming. And I've never even taken part in a C++ project.

Comment: @pm100 my teacher encourages us to work together and use stackoverflow before contacting them for help. prior to this discussion I didn't know about std::to_string and now I do and I'll actually remember it because I learned it through application. Im sorry someone made you feel like your work is only valid when you're on your own, I'm gonna keep asking for help and growing.

Comment: Interesting `for ( unsigned int i = 1; i++ < n; )` loop that can handle all `unsigned int` values of `n` including `UINT_MAX`.  I had never seen this approach for increasing loops albeit I have been using the same technique for downward loops using an unsigned index: `for ( size_t n = sizeof(array); i --> 0; )`.  In this case, it makes the code more difficult to grasp for beginners, a more classic approach is easier on them: `for ( unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

**In C++23 you can do this easily by using C++ views and ranges:**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

int calc_factorial(int num) {
   int sum = 1;
   while(num > 0) {
       sum = sum * num;
       num--;
   }
   return sum;
}

void print_factorial(const int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        std::cout << '0';
    } else {
        std::ranges::copy(
            std::views::iota(1) |
            std::views::take(num) |
            std::views::transform([](auto v){ return std::to_string(v); }) |
            std::views::join_with('x'),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    }

    std::cout << " = " << calc_factorial(num) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    for(const int num: std::views::iota(0, 12)) {
        print_factorial(num);
    }
}
```

```
0 = 1
1 = 1
1x2 = 2
1x2x3 = 6
1x2x3x4 = 24
1x2x3x4x5 = 120
1x2x3x4x5x6 = 720
1x2x3x4x5x6x7 = 5040
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8 = 40320
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9 = 362880
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10 = 3628800
1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10x11 = 39916800
```

The `std::views::iota(begin, end)` produces values from including `begin` to excluding `end`.

With `std::views::iota(1)` you create a endless sequence of values starting with `1`. (Note views are lazy evaluated!) The `std::views::take(num)` makes `num` stops generation after reaching `num`. You could have done the same by `std::views::iota(1, num + 1)`.

The `std::views::transform` converts the `int` values to `std::string` by calling `std::to_string` through a lambda. Alternatively, you can pass a reference or pointer to the function directly, but since `std::to_string` has multiple overloads, the `int` overload must be selected via `static_cast`. Alternatively, you can pass a reference or pointer to the function directly, but since `std::to_string` has multiple overloads, the `int` overload must be selected via `static_cast`. This is less readable than the lambda, but minimally more efficient, since a lambda up to C++20 always creates an empty object. As of C++23, you can suppress object creation for lambdas without capture by defining the function operator as a static function. This is then just as efficient as the cast.

```cpp
std::views::transform(static_cast<std::string(&)(int)>(std::to_string))
std::views::transform(static_cast<std::string(*)(int)>(std::to_string))
std::views::transform([](int v) static { return std::to_string(v); })
```

(Note: Make captureless lambdas `static` by default would unfortunately have broken backwards compatability.)

The `std::views::join_with` flattens the `std::string` to a sequence of `char`s and adds a `'x'` between these sequences. The result is a long sequence of `char`s containing the character sequence you wanted to create.

The `std::ranges::copy` copies this sequence of `char`s to `std::cout`.

The `join_with` view is C++23, the other views are C++20.

---

If you are stuck to an older standard then C++23 or if you just don't want to use the views and ranges approach, you can implement the print function as:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int calc_factorial(int num) {
   int sum = 1;
   while(num > 0) {
       sum = sum * num;
       num--;
   }
   return sum;
}

void print_factorial(const int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        std::cout << num;
    } else {
        std::cout << 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= num; ++i) {
            std::cout << 'x' << i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << " = " << calc_factorial(num) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        print_factorial(i);
    }
}
```

In fact, this implementation is probably better, as less complex and somewhat more efficient. (The other approach uses `std::to_string`, which is potentially slow).

However, the question lends itself so nicely to demonstrating the use of views and ranges, hence the detailed description of this approach. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need std::to_string (or std::stringstream).
There's only so many digits that you are going to use. So, define

```
   string digits = "0123456789";
```

and pick the relevant characters off with digits[n/10] or digits[n%10].

You can probably only make it to factorial(20) anyway.